# How can I print out a Joomla query?

Tags: joomla-3.x, database

Suppose you have constructed a query with Joomla.

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value', 'ordering')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'custom.%\''));
$query->order('ordering ASC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Example from here: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Is there a command to print out the query statement (not the results the but actual SQL)?

Comment: So that I can read the query as "SELECT * FROM .... "

Comment: why not use the debug mode?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to echo __toString()

```
echo($query->__toString());
```

you can fing more info here

https://docs.joomla.org/API16:JDatabaseQuery/_toString

Hope it helps

Comment: Would just like to note that when using this method, it dumps the query **with** the Joomla prefix `#__`.

Comment: echo (string) $query;

Answer (score 10):

You can also use Joomla's `replacePrefix` function which dumps out the query in a format that can be inserted straight into the likes of PhpMyAdmin.

Here's an example:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('something'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__content')); 
$db->setQuery($query);

// Dump the query
echo $db->replacePrefix((string) $query);
```

Will output the following:

```
SELECT `something` FROM `jos_content`
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use native `dump()` method: `echo $query->dump();`

Comment: I prefer using this one since it will print the db prefix as well.

Comment: This method does not work anymore. dump() is deprecated without replacement

Answer (score 5):

The `JDatabaseQuery` object has a `__toString()` function that outputs the query so you can do:

```
echo $db->getQuery();
```

Or if you want to pass it to a function you can explicitly cast it to a string first:

```
var_dump((string)$db->getQuery());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Joomla debug feature will give you a lot of information 
about the queries that are executed when your website loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $query;
```

will do fine.

this makes use of this code

```
echo($query->__toString());
```